# Oracle 10g select query by date returning no result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have some confusing problem.

```
 SQL> select login, status, date_modified from users where login = 'zack_661' and date_modified = '05-MAR-14';

no rows selected

SQL> select login, status, date_modified from users where login = 'zack_661' and date_modified = sysdate;

no rows selected
```

There is no result for both queries but if i'm not specifying date then it returned with result.

```
SQL> select login, status, date_modified from users where login = 'zack_661';

LOGIN                                                  STATUS DATE_MODI
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------
zack_661                                                    1 05-MAR-14

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
05-MAR-14
```

and here is the table schema.

```
SQL> desc users;

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
LOGIN                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
STATUS                                             NUMBER
DATE_CREATED                                       DATE
DATE_MODIFIED                                      DATE
```

i'm also trying using other function but still no result

```
SQL> select login, status, date_modified from users where login = 'zack_661' and date_modified = to_date('05-MAR-14','DD-MON-YY');

no rows selected

SQL> select to_date('05-MAR-14','DD-MON-YY') from dual;

TO_DATE('
---------
05-MAR-14
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

### Updated

Thanks to KevinKirkpatrick. I can conclude like this.

```
SQL> select login, status, date_modified from users where login = 'zack_661' and date_modified between TO_DATE('05-MAR-2014 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('05-MAR-2014 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

LOGIN                                                  STATUS DATE_MODI
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------
zack_661                                                    1 05-MAR-14
```

For anyone else thanks a lot for your help. I'm really appreciate it. I should help others to since i'm new here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't depend on the time, then you may try this

```
select login, status, date_modified from xdsl where login = 'zack_661' and trunc(date_modified)=to_date('05-MAR-14','DD-MON-YY');
```

Comment: Oracle can store time data along with DATE in a field with data type as DATE. So, whenever you write a query with a filter on date type field, its better to trunc the field or convert the same to date before doing the comparision as shown in the query above.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle DATE is stored to nearest second.  When you query DATE_MODIFIED, Oracle will format the date using your NLS_date_format.  Annoyingly, the default setting of this parameter does not display the hour/minute/second portion of the date value.  So by default, it will look like your DATE values are just whole-dates, even though they are not.  In your case, DATE_MODIFIED is almost certainly not exactly '05-MAR-2014' (which is actually 12:00 a.m. on march 5).  Hopefully the following example makes this clearer:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (DATE_MODIFIED DATE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (SYSDATE);

1 row created.

SQL> COLUMN DATE_MODIFIED FORMAT A20
SQL> SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE;

DATE_MODIFIED
--------------------
04-MAR-14

SQL> SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE DATE_MODIFIED = '04-MAR-14';

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_MODIFIED,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DATE_MODIFIED FROM EXAMPLE;

DATE_MODIFIED
--------------------
04-MAR-2014 21:40:45

SQL> SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE DATE_MODIFIED = TO_DATE('04-MAR-2014 21:40:45',
'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

DATE_MODIFIED
--------------------
04-MAR-14

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE;

DATE_MODIFIED
--------------------
04-MAR-2014 21:40:45

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot. From your explanation I can conclude like this. 

SQL> select login, status, date_modified from xdsl where login = 'zack_661' and date_modified between TO_DATE('05-MAR-2014 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('05-MAR-2014 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

    LOGIN                                                  STATUS DATE_MODI
    -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------
    zack_661                                                    1 05-MAR-14

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
select login, status, date_modified from xdsl where login = 'zack_661' and date_modified =to_date('05-MAR-14','DD-MON-YY');
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-nov/o62sql-1867727.html. Look at this for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  where date_modified  = to_date('31-DEC-95','DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I already did that in my question. :)